# image preview from thumbnail on click and with sliders: How do I make click and sliding work together?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an image preview from thumbnails that works on click of thumbnail by changing the preview src. I recently added previous and after navigation buttons. Both systems are working fine yet if I click on a thumbnail and then use the navigation buttons the preview will return to the starting image and not go next or previous. Here's the code to clarify:

```js
//thumbnail click
$(".gallery").click(function() {$("#bigImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));});
//image slider
$( document ).ready(function (){
                var slide = [];
                $(".gallery").each(function(){
                    slide.push(this.src);
                });
                console.log(slide);
                $(".galimaslirig").click(function(){

                    var bigSrc = $("#bigImage").attr("src");
                    console.log(bigSrc);
                    var slideCounter = slide.indexOf(bigSrc);
                    console.log(slideCounter)
                    if (slideCounter >= slide.length - 1){
                        slideCounter = -1;
                    } 
                    $("#bigImage").attr("src", slide[++slideCounter]);
                });
                $(".galimaslilef").click(function(){

                    var bigSrc = $("#bigImage").attr("src");
                    console.log(bigSrc);
                    var slideCounter = slide.indexOf(bigSrc);
                    console.log(slideCounter)
                    if (slideCounter <= 0){
                        slideCounter = slide.length;
                    } 
                    $("#bigImage").attr("src", slide[--slideCounter]);
                });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-12 biimdi">
      <button class="galimaslilef"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></button>
    <img class="img-fluid" id="bigImage" align="center" src="kids.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" alt="big screen" />
    <button class="galimaslirig"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
  </div>    
  <div class="col-12" id= "imageGallery" align="right">     
      <img class="gallery" src="./kids.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="kids" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./family.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="family" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./stance.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="stance" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./friends.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="friends" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./woman.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="woman" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./jump.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="jump" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./man.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="man" />
      <img class="gallery" src="./grind.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"  alt="grind" />
  </div>
```

I am guessing this is some kind of asynchronous issue in which I am not very good at. As you can see when I console log bigSrc it logs the right src but after assigning its index to slideCounter and console log it the result is always -1 in which I am guessing means undefined. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While T.Shah found the problem, the solution was not working "bigSrc" was logging undefined instead of -1 that I had. After doing a little research I used "$(this).attr('src').slice(2,)" in the each function to push it to the array. and then use the same slice method in the thumbnail click function. Here is the working code:

```
// the click function
$(".gallery").click(function() {
            $("#bigImage").attr("src", $(this).attr('src').slice(2,));
        });
//image slider
        $( document ).ready(function (){
            var slide = [];
            $(".gallery").each(function(){
                slide.push($(this).attr('src').slice(2,));
            });
            console.log(slide);
            $(".galimaslirig").click(function(){

                var bigSrc = $("#bigImage").attr("src");
                console.log(bigSrc);
                var slideCounter = slide.indexOf(bigSrc);
                console.log(slideCounter)
                if (slideCounter >= slide.length - 1){
                    slideCounter = -1;
                } 
                $("#bigImage").attr("src", slide[++slideCounter]);
            });
            $(".galimaslilef").click(function(){

                var bigSrc = $("#bigImage").attr("src");
                console.log(bigSrc);
                var slideCounter = slide.indexOf(bigSrc);
                console.log(slideCounter)
                if (slideCounter <= 0){
                    slideCounter = slide.length;
                } 
                $("#bigImage").attr("src", slide[--slideCounter]);
            });
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous next issue arises because of this - var bigSrc = $("#bigImage").attr("src"); This returns just the image name like kids.jpg.  Where as your array stores images with slide.push(this.src); - this gives full path.  So it always returns -1.  You can modify the function a little like this.

```
        $( document ).ready(function (){
            var slide = [];
            $(".gallery").each(function(){
                console.log(this.src);
                slide.push(this.src);
            });
            var bigImg =  document.getElementById('bigImage'); // big image id
            console.log(slide);
            $(".galimaslirig").click(function(){                    
                var bigSrc = bigImg.src; // big image source - full path
                console.log(bigSrc);
                var slideCounter = slide.indexOf(bigSrc);
                console.log(slideCounter)
                if (slideCounter >= slide.length - 1){
                    slideCounter = -1;
                } 
                $("#bigImage").attr("src", slide[++slideCounter]);
            });
            $(".galimaslilef").click(function(){
                var bigSrc = bigImg.src; // big image source - full path
                console.log(bigSrc);
                var slideCounter = slide.indexOf(bigSrc);
                console.log(slideCounter)
                if (slideCounter <= 0){
                    slideCounter = slide.length;
                } 
                $("#bigImage").attr("src", slide[--slideCounter]);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, man, you pointed me in the right direction. While you found the problem, the solution was not working "bigSrc" was logging undefined instead of -1 that I had. After doing a little research I used "$(this).attr('src').slice(2,)" in the each function to push it to the array. and then use the same slice method in the thumbnail click function.